# What am I not understanding updating R version?

Tags: r, rstudio

I went to RStudio to download 4.2.3 and updating my current version. I downloaded the new version, I checked in my computer it was updated

However when I check my version it's the old version, but checking for updating is not possible, because I'm supposed to have the newest version. All this is due to my problems to install caret package

Is there anything I am not seeing? I'm pretty unaware of core R and its working

[image]

Comment: R and RStudio are different things: R is the language, RStudio is the environment (IDE) that makes using R easier. Therefore you can have the latest RStudio version (like here) but not the latest R version (in your case you have 4.2.2 but 4.2.3 is available)

Comment: Also note that your problem with the package `caret` is not related to your R version: the error tells you that you need to update the package `vctrs` (which requires restarting the session), the warning tells you that `caret` was built with the latest R version but it shouldn't have an impact on your code. Still, if possible, I would update the R version by downloading it on the [r-project](https://www.r-project.org/) page

Comment: Thank you. The problem with vctrs is that it causes an infinite loop of restarting and error. Seems that uninstalling and installing fresh new works!